# Trouble booting Nix OS from USB device on a HP dragonfly g4 laptop

Tags: linux, boot, grub, nixos

I come to you in a time of great need! I've recently upgraded my laptop to a Hp dragonfly G4 and am hoping to run linux on it (I'm in MS edge right now and ever two seconds windows pings me with some strange notification, I want my linux back). Furthermore I would love to try out NixOS as I have only heard good things about the distro. **I am not looking to change my laptop nor do I want to opt for a different distribution!**

The setup:

- I run Windows 11
- I have installed the newest version of the NixOS Linux distro (GNOME 64 Intel) from this link: https://nixos.org/download
- I have flashed my USB using Rufus with following settings:

  - Boot selection: the iso I downloaded
  - I tried both MDR and GPT with the difference that I can see the harddrive partition in the GRUB shell only if I use GPT
  - the file system of my USB is NTFS and the cluster size is the default 4 KiB
  - I use one pass only

### Now here is the Problem statement:

If I then restart my Laptop and go into the boot menu, I am met with the option to select my USB device for a boot medium. If I do so and continue I am greeted with the GNU GRUB shell, not the normal Grub Boot selection. I can then look through all my partitions and check their insides, although most of them are "unknown filesystems". I seem to have two disks (hd1) and (hd0), the ladder of which is probably the USB. In a separate partition (hd0,gpt2) I find two files

- README.txt (I can't open that, as I am missing the cat command for some reason)
- efi/ (this has the following contents)

  - RUFUS/ (this tells me that I am looking at the USB)
  - Boot/  (this one contains four efi files)

[I have photographed the shell with the actual files for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJqAQ.jpg)

At this point I dont know what to do. I don't know enough about bootloading to use the shell to my advantage and I am not sure what the reason for this is. I have tested many settings at random and tried two USB sticks as well as Ubuntu which works. I really would love to become part of the NixOs community but the current circumstances hinder me greatly. If anyone has as much as an idea I would love for an answer

All the best,
CCI